# Getting the years since an event

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a dataset with pandas in which a maintenance work is done at a location. The maintenance is done at random intervals, sometimes a year, and sometimes never. I want to find the years since the last maintenance action at each site if an action has been made on that site. There can be more than one action for a site and the occurrences of actions are random. For the years prior to the first action, it is not possible to know the years since action because that information is not in the dataset.
I give only two sites in the following example but in the original dataset, I have thousands of them. My data only covers the years 2014 through 2017.

Action = 0 means no action has been performed that year, Action = 1 means some action has been done. Measurement is a performance reading related to the effect of the action. The action can happen in any year.

```
Site  Year   Action  Measurement
 A   2014     1         100
 A   2015     0         150
 A   2016     0         300
 A   2017     0         80
 B   2014     0         200
 B   2015     1         250
 B   2016     1         60
 B   2017     0         110
```

Given this dataset; I want to have a dataset like this:

```
Item  Year   Action  Measurement  Years_Since_Last_Action
 A   2014     1         100           1
 A   2015     0         150           2
 A   2016     0         300           3
 A   2017     0         80            4
 B   2015     1         250           1
 B   2016     1         60            1
 B   2017     0         110           2
```

Please observe the Year 2015 is filtered out for Site B because that year is prior to the first action for that site.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: The `Measurement` is not used?  You are just looking for a difference between the `Year` column values for the *last* time the `Action` was `1`?

Comment: Yes, the measurement will be aggregated based on the Years since action.

Comment: @Rajat Mishra - I tried using transform() function on the site group.

Comment: @wwii, yes, I am looking for a difference between the ``Year`` column values for the last time the ``Action`` was ``1``.

Comment: Are you only comparing `A`'s to `A`'s and `B`'s to `B`'s - (`Item` values)?

Comment: Yes, each site is compared in itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the code myself. It is messy but does the job for me. :)
The solution assumes that df_select has an integer index.

```
df_select = (df_select[df_select['Site'].map((df_select.groupby('Site')['Action'].max() == 1))])
years_since_action = pd.Series(dtype='int64')
gbo = df_select.groupby('Site')
for (key,group) in gbo:
    indices_with_ones = group[group['Action']==1].index
    indices = group.index
    group['Years_since_action'] = 0
    group.loc[indices_with_ones,'Years_since_action'] = 1

    for idx_with_ones in indices_with_ones.sort_values(ascending=False):
        for idx in indices:
            if group.loc[idx,'Years_since_action']==0:
                if idx>idx_with_ones:
                    group.loc[idx,'Years_since_action'] = idx - idx_with_ones + 1


    years_since_action = years_since_action.append(group['Years_since_action'])

df_final = pd.merge(df_select,pd.DataFrame(years_since_action),how='left',left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I will approach it:

```
import pandas as pd

from io import StringIO

import numpy as np

s = '''Site  Year   Action  Measurement
 A   2014     1         100
 A   2015     0         150
 A   2016     0         300
 A   2017     0         80
 B   2014     0         200
 B   2015     1         250
 B   2016     1         60
 B   2017     0         110
 '''

ss = StringIO(s)

df = pd.read_csv(ss, sep=r"\s+")


df_maintain = df[df.Action==1][['Site', 'Year']]
df_maintain.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df_maintain

def find_last_maintenance(x):
    df_temp = df_maintain[x.Site == df_maintain.Site]

    gap = [0]

    for ind, row in df_temp.iterrows():

        if (x.Year >= row['Year']):
            gap.append(x.Year - row['Year'] + 1)



    return gap[-1]

df['Gap'] = df.apply(find_last_maintenance, axis=1)

df = df[df.Gap !=0]
```

[image]

This generates the desired output.

Comment: this output does not give the result I was asking.

Comment: That is closer. :) But still not exactly it. If you look at my desired output, you'll see that for Site B, I shouldn't see 2014 observation. Also, the values for the years 2015, 2016, and 2017 should be [1,1,2] respectively.

Comment: apologies for my rush, I corrected it now. Do let me know if this works.